# Kendo Grid Filter on specific column : how to customize?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik, kendo-grid

I have filter on the specific column in Kendo grid and i would like to modify this column like on the image below:

[image]

I tried to do by setting on the column config by this way:

```
// ADD DATE PICKER FOR COLUMNS CREATION TIME
          if(value.filterable.cell.dataTextField == "creationTime") {
            //preparedGridColumnItem.AllowFiltering = false,
            preparedGridColumnItem.format = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}";
            preparedGridColumnItem.filterable = {
              ui: function (element) {
                element.kendoDatePicker({
                  format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
                });
              },
              cell: {
                operator: "eq",
                showOperators: false, // HIDE FILTER MENU
                template: function (arg) {
                  arg.element.kendoDatePicker({
                    format: "dd.MM.yyyy",
                    change: function (e){
                      console.log("Change :: " + kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd'));
                      var timestamp = moment(this.value()).unix();
                      console.log(timestamp);

                    }
                  });

                }
              }
            }
          }
```

But without luck.

I would like to have dropdown boxes not editable with predefined value to search.

How can i do it please?

I tried to find any working solution in documentation.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

But without the luck.
Many thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**

Filter is looking like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand: do you want to achieve a filter like the image you posted or do you want to use dropdowns instead of datepickers as shown in the image. Because in your code you are just trying to set datepickers.

Comment: If you want only datepickers you can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j72jj1v9/).

Comment: Datepickers are OK, i need to set only one non-editable, predefined logical operator for each field. One for is before and second for the is after. With No other options available.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
    if (e.field == "date") {
        var sels = e.container.find("select");
        var sel1 = $(sels[0]).data("kendoDropDownList");
        var sel2 = $(sels[2]).data("kendoDropDownList");

        sel1.select(3);
        sel1.enable(false);

        sel2.select(5);
        sel2.enable(false);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j72jj1v9/1/). [This doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit) helped me.

`e.container` refers to the filter widget. With it you can play around freely. Note that the event is just called once, at the initialization of the filter widget, and not at each open/close.

Updated code for `columnMenu`:

Just change the `filterMenuInit` to `columnMenuInit`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j72jj1v9/4/).

Update 2:

I have added the following code to the `columnMenuInit` event:

```
var dates = $(e.container).find('[data-role="datepicker"]');
$(dates[0]).data("kendoDatePicker").unbind("change");
$(dates[1]).data("kendoDatePicker").unbind("change");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j72jj1v9/5/). I just `unbind` the default change event of the datepickers, avoiding changing the dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks, but its not not working in my case. Can't it be caused by using more complex filter? (See image in my updated question).

Comment: Thanks, now is it better, but there is the issue with change of the operator after the selec of the date from date picker. Default and preselected is value "Is After" but after the date selection event is changed into the "Is equal value" and i dont know what is causing this..